# What would a gaint make it's house out of

Tags: natural-resources, metals, giant

For one the giant is much bigger than a normal human, To be precise about 110,000 feet tall and about 500 feet wide. Because of their size what would be some reliable things to make their houses and clothing out of. My thoughts were other killed giants but what are some other reliable natural resources that wouldn't be to inefficient or unreliable for a civilization of giants.

Comment: 110,000 feet tall and only 500 feet wide means this giant is more than 200 times as tall as they are wide. (So, like...a pole?) Are you sure your numbers properly represent your vision?

Comment: I like this question but the giants proportions seem a little too large. Maybe go with something like 300 feet tall. It would be tall, the question is still there but it would be easier to answer.

Comment: If giants exist which are 110000 feet tall, then you could as easily say "they use million-foot-tall trees to build their homes" as both are equally impossible with real-life physics.

Comment: Given that the giant is 4 times the height of Mt Everest any clothing would constitute a megastructure on the same order of difficulty as building a beanstalk into orbit.  There is no material currently existing that can be used for this.  Once you add the requirement for the material to be able to flex and allow free movement it shifts from "not yet existing" to "not conceivably possible".  Put bluntly, the question is unanswerable with the giant's dimensions as stated.

Comment: Also, unless the giant's nose is in its knees, it's going to have considerable trouble breathing :-)

Answer (score 3):

Exact numbers of size aside, why would a giant need clothes? The surface area is relatively smaller than the inside the bigger you are. That means a giant has a relatively small surface to lose heat from. They will be able to stay warm in more environments, meaning they need less or no clothes even without fur.

The more dangerous part is activities. If you are active you generate heat. Without proper ways to remove the heat you'll quickly overheat. That can lead to feeling bad, loss of consciousness, internal damage and even death. With relatively little skin it'll be difficult to cool down.

If these truly are multistory high giants a building for them would be a strange concept. They probably can weather most weather like most animals. If you do want a building, natural occuring is easiest. There's plenty examples of big caves where whole buildings have been build into. This does limit where they can live. If modern materials are available you should use concrete and steel, as well as upcoming plastics. These use currently used in many high-rise buildings, making it suitable for giant housing. But with the unclear parameters it kight not fit. Then the question comes around again. Why build buildings for being so incredibly large they can take most nature throws at them.

Comment: Why do humans wear clothes in warm places, or for activities like swimming where they're a hindrance?  Hint: it's not just for pockets :-)